# Issue with apply command in kubectl and .yml file

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubectl

In a class and working on a kubernetes portion. I copied her json file by hand as it was in a video where we were asked to copy it from her screen. I ran the file through a yml validator and it said it was valid yet I get an error when running the apply command in terminal.

the .yml file is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: 'nginx:1.14.2'
          ports:
            - 'containerPort:80'
```

when running `kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment` I get the following error:
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "nginx-deployment.yml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Container.spec.template.spec.containers.ports of type v1.ContainerPort

Comment: Kubernetes has excellent API documentation. Here's [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.29/#deployment-v1-apps) (for v1.29) and drilling down, here's [`Container`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.29/#container-v1-core) and finally [`ContainerPort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.29/#containerport-v1-core) which corresponds your `ports` sequence (array). See that `containerPort` is a field taking an integer and so you need `containerPort: 80` (i.e. ditch the `'...'`).

Answer (score -2):

It's telling you that this portion:

```
ports:
            - 'containerPort:80'
```

is a string and its expecting an integer. You cannot have `'containerport'` here. You could have `80` as an integer. But not a string.